# Time comparison in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nsdate

I am storing the date and time in strings using NSUserDefaults when an action is performed. next time the app is run, I want to check the time since the last date and time, and display a message if this is greater than a specified time period.

Is this possible?

In `viewDidLoad` I retrieve the NSUserDefaults with the saved date and time, and I get the current date, but how do i compare them, and 'do something' if the time difference is bigger than specified?

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE. You use it to write your program. It doesn't run the program, it doesnt offer you libraries or framework you use when compiling. what you mean is cocoa(-touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [timeIntervalSinceDate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-timeIntervalSinceDate_) method.

By the way, you can store NSDates directly in NSUserDefaults.  You don't need to convert them to/from strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate * lastUpdate = [defaults valueForKey:@"mysettingdate"];

if(!lastUpdate){
    lastUpdate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
}

NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]; 
NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + timeZoneOffset;
NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];

NSDateComponents *diff = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:lastUpdate toDate:gmtDate options:0];

NSLog(@"diff in minutes:%d", [diff minute]); //or hour, days, seconds
if ([diff minute]>0)  {
    //do your stuff :)       
}
```

Comment: `NSDate`s are always in GMT.  You don't need to do the time zone correction.  Also, you don't need to get the date components.  You can directly get the number of seconds between two `NSDate`s with the methosd in my answer.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right, that was just my complete implementation